# Storing Django FileField with leading slash

Tags: django, django-storage

I have a database used by two different systems and as a result I actually need the FileField value to have a leading slash, like so:

```
/dirs/filename.ext
```

In Django, however, FileField values can't have a leading slash since it breaks how they interact with `MEDIA_ROOT`.

So my suspicion is that I either have to create a custom storage class or somehow customize FileField so that the leading slash is stripped out when read and restored when saved.

---

In case anyone is wondering why I am doing this: I am mirroring the files on a separate ***non*-Django** server.

On the Django server, the files are relative to the media root. So supposing the media root was `/path/to/myapp/media`, a file with the path `dirs/filename.ext` would exist at `/path/to/myapp/media/dirs/filename.ext`.

Meanwhile, when mirrored on the other server, they are stored relative to the webroot. So the path is equivalent to the absolute URL of the file (e.g. the file `dirs/filename.ext` is stored in `/path/to/example.com/dirs/filename.ext` and accessed as `http://example.com/dirs/filename.ext`).

Both servers are using the same database.

I realize that one solution is prepending a slash everywhere the field is used on the other server, but that is across a number of different source files, whereas in Django thanks to the record model I *should* be able to make a change just in the `models.py` file and it will work across the entire Django site.

---

So far I have tried creating a custom version of `FileField` and it correctly prepends the `/` on lookup and saving *but* I cannot get it to *remove* the leading slash when used within the Django app.

---

#### Example

Imagine a record called Tool with a PDF file for its manual. On the Django server, it would be displayed in a template thusly:

```
<h1>{{ tool.name }}</h1>
<p>{{ tool.description }}</p>
<p><a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ tool.file.url }}">Link to Manual</a></p>
```

Meanwhile on the other server it's more like (this is CF code):

```
<h1>#GetTool.tool_name#</h1>
<p>#GetTool.tool_description#</p>
<p><a href="#GetTool.tool_file#">Link to Manual</a></p>
```

In the second server example, it needs to be an absolute URL.

So, to be clear:

- the second server is not a Django project
- it would be much more time-consuming to change the code on the second server rather than the first
- therefore the value in the FileField needs to be an absolute URL in order to be compatible with Django, but needs to be saved with a leading slash in order to be compatible with the second server.

Comment: I still don't understand why the / is needed. If `MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/myapp/media/'` and `MEDIA_URL = 'http://example.com/' it's all fine and dandy. What problem would the leading '/' solve? How is it used on the other server?

Comment: And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server, but I can't imagine how the DBMS would affect *anything* since Django uses an ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this. The trick was also subclassing FieldFile in addition to FileField:

```
class LeadingSlashFieldFile(files.FieldFile):
    def __init__(self, instance, field, name):
        name = re.sub(r'^/', '', name)
        super(LeadingSlashFieldFile, self).__init__(instance, field, name)

class LeadingSlashFileField(models.FileField):
    attr_class = LeadingSlashFieldFile

    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if hasattr(value, 'name'):
            value = value.name
        if value[0] <> '/':
            value = "/" + value
        return super(LeadingSlashFileField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(LeadingSlashFileField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value is None:
            return None
        value = unicode(value)
        if value[0] <> '/':
            value = "/" + value
        return value
```

This appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating custom field. Something like:

```python
class MyFileField(models.Field):
    attr_class = MyFieldFile

    def get_directory_name(self):
        return os.path.normpath(force_unicode(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(smart_str(self.upload_to))))

    def get_filename(self, filename):
        return os.path.normpath(self.storage.get_valid_name(os.path.basename(filename)))

    def generate_filename(self, instance, filename):
        return os.path.join(self.get_directory_name(), self.get_filename(filename))

    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if hasattr(value, 'name'):
            value = value.name
        return super(FileField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        "Returns field's value prepared for saving into a database."
        # Need to convert File objects provided via a form to unicode for database insertion
        if value is None:
            return None
        return unicode(value)
```

This is default django-1.4 code. And you should modify it to add slash where needed

You should also subclass django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile (you can see MyFieldFile in example) because when you access field value you actualy get this class. And this class have save method that modifies path on save. So remove slash in that class.

Methods of this two classws call methods of storage class so another option is to create alternative storage

```python
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class MyStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def path(self, name):
        try:
            path = safe_join(self.location, name)
        except ValueError:
            raise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
        return os.path.normpath(path)

    def _save(self, name, content):
        full_path = self.path(name)
        # many lines of code
        return name  # this is used as filename in database
```

Configure default storage in django settings:

```python
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'yourapp.import.path.MyStorage'
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy the code of a class, just to add a '/' somewhere. `MyFifleField` should inherit from `models.FileField` and [override](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) the methods that need the '/'; I think the `get_prep_...`

Comment: > You shouldn't copy the code of a class
You are right. I just wanted to show what methods class has and what they do by default.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then why can't you just do a method that appends or removes the slash for the field instead of doing a special field?

It's a bit hackish but I guess it works.

```
class MyModelWithAppendingSlash(models.Model):
    my_file = FileField(options_go_here)

    def my_file_appended(self):
        return path = '/' + self.my_file.filename

    def my_file_slash_removed(self):
        return my_file.filename[1:]
```

Then when you reference the model in your django app do `myModelWithAppendingSlashInstance.my_file_appended()` or `.my_file_slash_removed()`

I snipped a lot of the code and you have to modify it but you get the gist of what I'm trying to achieve here. This might be totally wrong for you but this is how I interpret your question.

Comment: I need it to be *stored* with the leading slash because the second app isn't a Django app. I guess I didn't make it clear in the original question?

Comment: So long as you are using FileField, it will *always* be saved **without** a leading slash. I need it saved **with** a leading slash. I could care less about its leading-slashitude when using it **within** the Django server.

Answer (score 0):

Without a line of code, you could fix this using a VIEW in the database. Just create a view that concatenates '/' (or '`http://example.com/`' if you want the url to be really absolute) and the path.

```
CREATE VIEW CF_appname_tool AS
SELECT [other attributes], '/' + file as file
FROM appname_tool;
```

I needed to know that you [use SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692413/storing-django-filefield-with-leading-slash#comment22616692_15692413), because the string concatenation operator differs per DBMS.

I suspect changing the CF code to select from CF_appname_tool is too much hassle. You can move your data from appname_tool to `some_other_name` and set the [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) option on your Django Tool model:

```
class Tool(model.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_other_name'
```

and create the `appname_tool` VIEW as a selection from `some_other_name`:

```
CREATE VIEW appname_tool AS
SELECT [other attributes], '/' + file as file
FROM some_other_name;
```

You could listen to the [post_syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_syncdb) signal if you want to create the VIEW programmatically in production.

Comment: So then I actually need to do the reverse: create a view for Django that *removes* the leading slash. But then I wouldn't be able to save to the view from Django, right? An interesting solution but not sure if it will work, since I think a view with a calculated field would be read only. For sure the calculated field will be read only, so there wouldn't be a straightforward way for Django to save to it.

Comment: @JordanReiter: No.. I've clarified my answer. You still make a view for CF that *adds* the slash.

Comment: Okay, just to clarify: I create the view for CF, *not* for Django. And I guess I renamed my original table to something like `TableName_Original` and the view to `TableName`?

Comment: I think I'll just work some more on my original approach of just making Django strip off the leading slash when getting the record, and prepending it when saving.

Comment: Updating can be handled with a trigger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx

Comment: If I had to choose between the real table (not the view) having the correct path and being able to mess with the file in Django, I'd pick the table every time. So considering that, I'll either get it to work in Django or won't do it at all. But thanks for looking at it from another angle.