# Django multiple media fields not being uploaded to S3

Tags: python, django, docker, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have multiple media fields in my model I just added media_thumbnail to a model, I basically need to get the first frame out of the video and then store it. I have used **Django 's built-in S3 uploading mechanism** which by default sends to the bucket which is defined in  ***settings.py*** such as `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` and etc. It works only when I do not create a field for thumbnail in my model instance.

I am using django as my backend as you might have guessed and I have dockerized the whole process

**models.py**

```
media_path = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
media_thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
media = Media(
       media_path=file,
       media_thumbnail=thumbnail,
       media_type=request.data.get('med_type', None))
```

This is the function I am using to generate thumbnail out of a video.

```
def generate_thumbnail(video):
    path = video.temporary_file_path()
    thumbnail = video.name.split('.')[0]
    thumbnail += "_thumbnail.jpg"
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), thumbnail)
    try:
        (
            ffmpeg
            .input(path, ss="00:00:00.000")
            .filter('scale', 640, -1)
            .output(thumbnail, vframes=1)
            .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True,overwrite_output=True)
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomException("someting went wrong", e)
    finally:
        with open(filepath) as f:
            myfile = ImageFile(f)
        os.remove(filepath)
    return myfile
```

I am returning an object type  `<class 'django.core.files.images.ImageFile'>` which should be uploaded to S3. but after I try to send a request to a specific endpoint which is supposed to create a thumbnail and throw both video and thumbnail to **AWS S3**, I get this is error.

```
    "result": {
        "success": false,
        "data": "Attempted access to '/code/somemedianame_thumbnail.jpg' denied."
    }
}
```

If there is anything that could help me please do not hesitate, responses are more than welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the leading slash

Reference

['Suspicious Operation: Attempted access to "" denied' while loading static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529912/suspicious-operation-attempted-access-to-denied-while-loading-static-files)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, How I am supposed to remove the leading slash, that is how it is returned from django.core.files constructor

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692413/storing-django-filefield-with-leading-slash